# teamslogon.aspx not working in Teams Chat Tabs

Tags: microsoft-teams

The teamslogon.aspx does not seem to be working properly when used in Teams **Chat Tabs**.

My understanding is that teamslogon.aspx is supposed to take care of the authentication when redirecting to SharePoint content in Teams.

While this works fine for **Channel Tabs** it does not work for **Chat Tabs** (of type Website).

For example, a Chat Tab with the content url :

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/ContosoNet/_layouts/15/teamslogon.aspx?SPFX=true&dest=/sites/ContosoNet/Home%20page.aspx
```

Will return a 200 (OK) and show a loading forever.

Whereas the same url in a Channel Tab would redirect to :

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/ContosoNet/Home%20page.aspx
```

with the proper cookies to access SharePoint content.

Is there any way for a Chat Tab to show content from SharePoint in Teams (both in app and in browser) while not already having Sharepoint cookies in the browser?

**Edit :**
You can reproduce the teamslogon.aspx not working by creating a Website **Chat Tab** with the Graph API using this query :

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/{chat-id}/tabs
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "displayName": "My Test Tab",
    "configuration": {
        "contentUrl": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/ContosoNet/_layouts/15/teamslogon.aspx?spfx=true&dest=https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/ContosoNet/MyLibrary/MyPage.aspx",
        "websiteUrl": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/ContosoNet/MyLibrary/MyPage.aspx",
        "wikiDefaultTab": false
    },
    "teamsApp@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/com.microsoft.teamspace.tab.web"
}
```

You would need to replace {chat-id} with a valid chat id hosted on your tenant. And also update the websiteUrl and contentUrl to valid paths on your tenant.

While the tab will be created using this query, it will show a loading forever when accessed without already having SharePoint cookies.

Comment: Could you please share sample/minimal code for us to repro the issue?

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT I have edited my question with a the Microsoft Graph Rest API query I am using.

Comment: Recently I was able to see the Sharepoint content in Chat/Channel tabs without making any changes. Could you please try again and confirm this? Also please share the console logs if you still get loading symbol?

Comment: I have retried opening the tab without any changes. I still get the same loading.
Here are my console logs : https://pastebin.com/LAGrxgjs

Comment: Engineering team has gone through the logs and said that the log provided are not useful as they are not showing anything about TeamsLogon.aspx. Internal team wants to get answers for the below questions. Could you please help?   1) How is the customer adding the tab?   2) Can the customer add manually the SharePoint tab and see if the issue occurs in that way?

Comment: Could you please share details on the above ask?